# PDO - Insert new row when duplicate detected based on 3 values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Currently I run a `SELECT` query on a table and if the `num_rows` is zero i then run a new function that `INSERT`s the record into the table. This seems very inneficient and I am struggling to find a good solution.

Current set up (simplified):
Select Function -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1 = ".$val1." AND col4 = ".$val4." AND col6 = ".$val6
// rest of code returns $numRows variable
```

If no `$numRows` is `0` then run a fresh query inserting the new record.

```
if($numRows == 0) {
    try {
        $dbh = $this->_dbSite;
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2, col3, col4, col4, col6, col7) VALUES (:val1, :val2, :val3, :val4, :val5, :val6, :val7");
        $stmt->bindParam(':val1', $val1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':val2', $val2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':val3', $val3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':val4', $val4, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':val5', $val5, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':val6', $val6, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':val7', $val7, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    $message = "Sorry this record already exists";
}
```

Table structure:

```
col1   | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7
________________________________________________
user1    abc    sol    red    doo     3a    def
user2    abc    ast    Blue   doo     4a    def
user1    abc    ast    blue   doo     3a    def
user4    abc    ast    red    doo     6a    def
user1    abc    ast    Green  doo     3a    def
user2    abc    ast    red    doo     7a    def
user1    abc    ast    red    doo     3a    def
```

The above example should be avoided as the first and last rows are identical in terms of `col1,col4` and `col6`

This does not seem the most efficient way of doing this. Has anybody encountered this before? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the combination of `col1`, `col4`, and `col6` is intended to be unique -- meaning that it should only appear once, then you can do this with `insert on duplicate key update` and a unique index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_myTable_col1_col4_col6 on (mytable, col1, col4, col6)

INSERT INTO myTable(col1, col2, col3, col4, col4, col6, col7)
    VALUES (:val1, :val2, :val3, :val4, :val5, :val6, :val7)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = VALUES(col1);
```

The update part is a no-op -- it just prevents an error from returning.

You can also do:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(col1, col2, col3, col4, col4, col6, col7)
    SELECT :val1, :val2, :val3, :val4, :val5, :val6, :val7
    FROM dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM myTable t2
                      WHERE t2.col1 = :val1 and t2.col4 = :val4 and t2.col6 = :val6
                     );
```

This will work regardless of whether or not the columns need to be unique.

Comment: The first option looks efficient. The `cols` will be unique to that user ID. I'm not sure it would work in this instance.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: In that case you would put a `user_id` column in the table and make it part of the `UNIQUE KEY`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Shouldnt that be `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_myTable_col1_col4_col6 on mytable  (col1, col4, col6);`?

Comment: I've added a table structure example to my question. As you can see the cols are not unique within the whole table. Only unique per user within the table.

Comment: Yeah so `col1` is you user so by adding a unique key with `(col1, col4, col6)` you are doing the correct thing - ie. a row is only a duplicate if all 3 of those columns have the same value in another row. So his advice still stands though i think he may have gotten the syntax incorrect for creating the index/key.

Comment: I have just tried this and it did not work. After looking into it I think this is because one of the columns I am inserting into needs to be a primary key or have a unique constraint.